# tomcat putting quotes around the cookie value

Tags: tomcat

I have a strange issue. The problem is when I am running tomcat 6 on my machine, it puts quotes in the cookie value. For example if a cookie name is A and its value is `key=us&val=wdc`, it puts a quote around the value and the value looks like `"key=us&val=wdc"`. The problem is, I do not want tomcat to put such extra quotes in the cookie value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible solution is to use tomcat 5.5.12.